# ListView automatically scrolling to its top

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have ListView at the bottom of my layout.

```
<LinearLayout
..
>

<ImageViews
..
/>
<ImageViews
..
/>

<ListView..
..
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If I open the Activity, it automatically scrolls to top of listview when the adapter gets updated. (i.e, I need scroll up to see above images).

Could not found any correct solution for this problem.